# Rank of completion of a module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $\hat R$ denote the $m$-adic completion of $R$ and $\hat M\cong M\otimes {\hat R}.$

***Is there any relation between rank$_R{M}$ and rank$_{\hat R}{\hat M}.$***

Comment: What do you mean by rank?

Comment: They are equal.

Comment: @user26857 Could you please explain it. It is not clear to me.

Comment: Why do people always ask what the rank is? Over every commutative ring with unity, you can always define it as the maximal size of a linear independent subset. If the ring gets more convenient, one has other definitions. But at the very least, one has this basic definition.

Comment: By flatness the rank can only increase. By faithfully flatness, the rank cannot increase.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.